# How to get the typeof(T) from a generic method with base type constraint?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following spec to help illustrate the problem:

```
class when_getting_type_of_generic_argument_using_subtype_instance
{
    static GenericTypeTester _genericTypeTester;
    static IPet _dog;
    static Type _result;

    Establish context =
        () =>
        {
            _genericTypeTester = new GenericTypeTester();

            _dog = new Dog();
        };

    Because of =
        () => _result = _genericTypeTester.Test(_dog);

    It should_return_the_subtype =
        () => _result.ShouldEqual(_dog.GetType());
}

class Dog : IPet
{
}

interface IPet
{
}

class GenericTypeTester
{
    public Type Test<T>(T dog) where T : IPet
    {
        return typeof (T);
    }
}
```

The spec above fails with the following message:

> Expected: System.RuntimeType:[Pepino.ScenarioRunner.Selenium.Specs.Dog]
>     But was:  System.RuntimeType:[Pepino.ScenarioRunner.Selenium.Specs.IPet]

I need the result to be of type `Dog`. Is there something I can do without using reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the type being used at runtime versus compile time.

Because you declared `_dog` as an `IPet`, the variable passed into the generic method is an `IPet` at compile time despite being a `Dog` at runtime. Thus the compiler uses `IPet` for the generic parameter, even though the object at runtime is a `Dog`. Since you used `typeof(T)`, you get the exact type given to the generic method by the compiler.

This can be seen by changing the type of `_dog` to `Dog` instead of `IPet`, which will then cause the compiler to infer the correct type.

This can also be avoided by explicitly casting the object as `dynamic`:

```
() => _result = _genericTypeTester.Test(_dog as dynamic);
```

Which will force the compiler to hold off the type inference until runtime, at which point it will determine that the object is type `Dog`. This is generally not a good idea for production code, however, since `dynamic` types are rather slow.

Comment: Change `static IPet _dog;` to `static Dog _dog;` and you will see the type change to Dog

Comment: @Grax technically true, so I'll integrate that into my answer

Comment: @Grax is correct, but at runtime, I don't have that luxury. The type has to remain IPet. BUT, your "trick" of casting as dynamic made the spec pass immediately.

Comment: Perhaps your GenericTypeTester should return dog.GetType() instead of typeof(T) if you are wanting the runtime type of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the constrait "class" to your method :

```
 class GenericTypeTester
 {
   public Type Test<T>(T dog) where T : IPet, class
   {
     return typeof (T);
   }
 }
```

Comment: This would prevent the rest of the code as-is from compiling, since object `_dog` is an `IPet` and thus stops meeting the given constraints. It also doesn't solve the given problem asked